# php5 cannot connect to oracle by apache

Tags: php, linux, oracle, apache2, oci8

i use Linux Mint, Apache2, PHP5, Oracle Xe 11 and without SELINUX installed. 
i have succes install oci8 on my machine. i have set oci8 extention on /etc/php5/mods-available and i checked with phpinfo(), oci8 is enabled.

i try connect to oracle. i have this php code:

```
    <?php
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
echo "[1]start connect<br>\n";
$conn = oci_new_connect('usertest', 'pwtester', 'localhost/XE');
echo "[2]check connection<br>\n";
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    echo "[3]Connection is error<br>\n";
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo "[4]test query\n";
$sql = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM users');
oci_execute($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

this code is working on php-cli and show the table. but, when accessed from browser, this code is not working with no result error returned. and flow of code is finish with "[3]Connection is error
\n" message.

how to solve this problem?

Adding information:

i try use php serve with this php command:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

and the php code is can connect to oracle.

[update]

i try to add this code on the top of code.

```
PutEnv("ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe");
PutEnv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib");
```

and the code is running.
and i think, the problem is Variable Environment.

Answer (score 0):

You enabled oracle extention only in php.ini for cli. You should enable it in php.ini for web too. Write simple php script

```
<?php echo php_info();
```

And open it in browser and check php.ini path.
Also may be you fogot to restart Apache or php-fpm

Comment: i have restart my PC. and i have run a this command
"echo 'extension=oci8.so'>>/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" and on phpinfo page is oci8 is enabled.

Comment: @mosleim what stored in $e variable after `$e = oci_error();` ?

Comment: it's just result 'false'.

Comment: Oci_error should return array. Do `var_dump($e)` and show result

Comment: return "bool(false)"

Comment: i just add the code with    `PutEnv("ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe");
PutEnv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib");` the code is can connect.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 11g + WAMP + Windows
This tutorial shows you how to use PHP with Oracle Database 11g.
First of all lets assume that i am using windows 7 64bit along with oracle
database 11G and wamp server, so I have already downloaded Oracle instant
client x64. if you are using 32bit windows then download 32bit client
otherwise it wont work.
Steps : -
1.Install oracle database 11g XE

2.Install WAMP

3.Download appropriate oracle instant client

4.Extract all the content of Oracle instant client and copy all
the .DLL files and paste into the directory like this
D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin

5.Turn on the Wamp server and left click on the icon > php >
PHP extension > check the php_oci8_11g only.
if you are using oracle database older then 11g like 10g then
you must check on php_oci8 only.

6.Turn up the oracle database 11g XE services. Also the
OracleServiceORCL should be there in services.

7.write a PHP code to Connect oracle with database 11g XE , and
save the code in www directory of wamp server. Below is the

```
<?php
$userName = "username"; $password = "paswword"; $dtabasePort = "1521"; $serverName = "localhost";
$databaseName = "ORCL";
$c = oci_connect($userName, $password, "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =
TCP)(HOST =$serverName)(PORT = $dtabasePort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$databaseName)))");
print_r($c); ?>
```

Enjoy !!!!